# Django test for POST always returns 400

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Form and view all work just fine in browser and time to add tests to make sure the view continues to work.

Problem is the test always returns 400

form:

```
class DogForm(forms.Form):
    dog_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    dog_type = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
```

view:

```
class DogRequestView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name='dog_request.html'
    def get(self, request):
        form = DogForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    def post(self, request):
        form = DogForm(request.POST)
        process_status = 'initial'
        if form.is_valid():
            stuff()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'status': process_status})
```

test:

```
class LabTests(TestCase):
    def test_DogForm(self):
        form_data = {
            'dog_name': 'Test name',
            'dog_type': 'k9'
        }
        self.client.login(username="test@acme.com", password="test")
        response = self.client.post("/kenel/dog-catalog/dog-request", form_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

url:

```
url(r'^kenel/dog-catalog/dog-request$', dog_catalog.DogRequestView.as_view()),
```

test output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/NSPF-171805/nsp-dev-portal/cloudlab/tests/test_forms.py", line 32, in test_DogForm
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you share your form?

Comment: Perhaps you have another URL pattern that is matching `/kenel/dog-catalog/dog-request`.

Comment: Also, you possible, share your terminal traceback too

Comment: Maybe the error is where `stuff()`  goes.

Comment: @grouchoboy no. To make sure I commented all that out and simply put in `print('Dog')` and am still getting the 400. If I fill in the form, Dog is printed. Just the test that fails...

Comment: mmm Which line is 32 of `test_forms.py`? Is there more information in the traceback? Do you create the user `test@acme.com` in the test setup?

Comment: As the traceback shows, line 32 is the `self.assertEqual`. Yes, the user is created and used to confirm the form and view work via the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add “data” in your post.

```
response = self.client.post("/kenel/dog-catalog/dog-request", data=form_data)
```

Comment: None of the examples I've seen show this as need. I did make the suggested change but still get a 400 response

Comment: the signature of the `post` method is `def post(self, path, data=None, format=None, content_type=None,
             follow=False, **extra)` so the `data` keywork is not neccesary in this case.